# Access django on raspberry pi from LAN

Tags: django, apache2, raspberry-pi

I installed **Django** and can access the test page while on my **Raspberry Pi** by going to `127.0.0.1:8000`.

However, when I am on my LAN and try `192.168.1.23:8000` I get nothing.

I suspect because I'm running `apache2`, I need to listen or forward the port? If I try `192.168.1.23` I successfully get the `/var/www` test page showing "it works".

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If run by manage.py, by default, only listens locally. So you have to start django using

```
manage.py runserver 0.0.0.0:8000
```

to let it listen on other addresses too.

If run by apache via WSGI or FCGI please supply a copy of the config file.